# Is there any possible balance update for an account on a "proposals" operation type?

Tags: node, protocol

I am trying to capture any operation that has a balance change - curious about the proposals operation and if there is any possibility that a balance can be updated?

Answer (score 1):

Neither `proposals` nor `ballot` operations affect account balance.